# How to Get Menu Items on Same Row

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, hamburger-menu

http://thehamburgercollection.com/shop/

If you look at the menu, you'll notice that all of the menu items are aligned left within a container in a single column. But what I want is for them to spread out evenly in a single row, and then to collapse into a hamburger menu at tablet and mobile size.

I know that `<ul>` is by default a block element, so I tried giving the `<ul>` with the id `"menu-navigation-1"` and the class of `"menu"` a style of

```
display:inline-block;
```

But nothing's happening.

I also tried assigning

```
display:inline-block;
```

to the div that encompasses the ul, which has a class of `"menu-navigation-container"`, but that didn't work either. Once I'm able to distribute the menu items evenly in a single row, I'll be able to create the hamburger menu. [This](https://www.watsonimagingcenter.com/) is a perfect example of how we want the menu to behave.

Comment: You could use `display: inline-block` but in your `li.menu-item` elements, not your `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! The list item (`li`) elements need to have `display: inline-block;`, not the list itself (`ul`).

This will work:

```
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px; /* add a gap between items */
}
```

Comment: Yeah that did it. So then <li>'s are also block elements by default? Also, is there a way to tell the <li>'s to "distribute evenly within the container", since right now there's a margin to the right of "My Account"?

Comment: (1) `li` are `display: list-item;` by default, which functions similarly to a block element. Just so you know, you can see default styles in your browser's development tools when you select an element. 

(2) To allow your content to distribute evenly, undo the above code from this example and instead use flex on the `ul` as such: `.menu { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }` (with no changes needed on the `.menu-item` elements).

Comment: Good to know - Perfect. Thanks!